# Can these sectors be represented as a function of the radius?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Consider a semi-circle with radius R, here 4 units.
The triangles are drawn at intervals, R/2,R/4,R/8.... from the base of the circle(m).

The summation of the areas of the triangles==$1/2Rcos(θ1)Rsin(θ1)+1/2(R/2)^2cos(θ2)sin(θ2)+...$

$(Where $θ1=π/6, $LH=(\sqrt{AH^2-(R/2+R/4)^2}),θ2==>arctan(R\sqrt{7}/4)), θ3=arctan(R\sqrt{15}/8)...)$

The summation of triangle areas and the sector areas must be $πR^2/2$

However the individual areas of the sectors are hard to pin down as a function of R, but they might be analogous to sectors from an ellipse.

Can these sectors be represented as a function of R?

Comment: How can I derive the values of $θ2,θ3...$ as a function of $θ1$?? Are the angles in an infinte GP? Or are the areas of the triangles in a gp?

Comment: It would be simple to get the partial sums of the geometric series to obtain the vertical distance from circle center to the lower line of an arbitrary one of the triangles. Once that is known, Pythagorean theorem gives the width of the base. Finally angles via arctan,

Comment: Yes thank you, I tried the same procedure for the triangles. But the sectors remain adamantly elusive.

Comment: @Lithium: *"I tried the same procedure for the triangles. But the sectors remain adamantly elusive."* Please edit your question to include the work that you've done. (Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) This will help readers avoid spending time on portions of the problem you have already solved or explaining things you already understand. ... Good luck!

Comment: @Lithium: Thanks for the edit. ... However, your $\arctan$ formulas for the $\theta_k$ shouldn't have $R$ in them; I can't tell if the calculations are otherwise correct, because it's not *entirely* clear to me which angles you're calling $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\theta_3$, etc. If you mean the angles at $E$, $G$, $I$, $\ldots$, then one way to calculate them is via $$\sin\theta_k= 2^{-(k+1)/2}$$ Interestingly, the formula predicts $\theta_0=45^\circ$ and $\theta_{-1}=90^\circ$, which one *could* assign geometric meaning (the latter being a little tricky) in your figure.

Comment: Ohh so the sin functions of the angles make a GP, cool!! And yes it's the angles at E,G,I.... And I made a mistake by adding the R in the arctan expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The altitudes of the stack of triangles are $h_i=R/2^i$, $i\ge 1$.
Cartesian coordinates on the circle are $(x_i,y_i)$, where the horizontal bases
of the triangles are at $y$-coordinates
$$
y_i=-\sum_{j=1}^i h_j=-R\sum_{j=1}^i 1/2^j=-R(1-\frac{1}{2^i}),
$$
negative because they are below the center line.
The half widths of the bases are (according to $x^2+y^2=R^2$) at the coordinates
$$
x_i=\pm\sqrt{R^2-R^2(1-\frac{1}{2^i})^2} = \pm R\sqrt{\frac{2^{i+1}-1}{2^{2i}}}
= \pm R\frac{1}{2^i}\sqrt{2^{i+1}-1}
$$
so there are closed formulas for all points E,F,G,H,I,J,N,O... on the circle.
The sum of all triangular areas (individually half product of base and height) is
$$
\sum_{i\ge 1} h_i|x_i| = R^2\sum_{i\ge 1}  \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{1}{2^i}\sqrt{2^{i+1}-1} \approx 0.692647496111156627318281329241865 R^2.
$$
$$
=R^2 \sum_{i\ge 1}
\frac{1}{2^{2i-i/2-1/2}}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2^i}} 
$$
$$
=R^2 \surd 2 \sum_{i\ge 1}
\frac{1}{2^{3i/2}}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2^i}}      
$$
$$
=R^2 \surd 2 \sum_{i\ge 1} \sum_{j\ge 0}
\frac{1}{2^{3i/2}}\binom{1/2}{j}(-)^j \frac{1}{2^{(i+1)j}}             
$$
and by inserting $j=0,1,2\ldots$
$$
=R^2\surd 2\left[\frac{\surd 2}{4-\surd 2}-\frac{\surd 2}{4(8-\surd 2)}-\frac{\surd 2}{32(16-\surd 2)}
-\frac{\surd 2}{128(32-\surd 2)}-\cdots
\right]
$$
$$
=R^2\left[\frac{2}{4-\surd 2}-\sum_{j\ge 1} \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots (2j-3)}{j!2^{2j}(2^{j+2}-\surd 2)}\right].
$$
The angles $\theta_i$ from the plumb line to the points F, H, J,..., i.e. the angles KAF, LAH, MAJ and so
on are $\cos\theta_i=|y_i|/R = 1-2^{-i}$, i.e., $\tan \theta_i=\frac{\sqrt{2^{i+1}-1}}{2^i-1}$.

The area of the circular segment below the $i$th triangle and still inside the circle
is $C_i\equiv R^2[2\theta_i-\sin(2\theta_i)]/2$,
where
$$
\sin(2\theta_i)=2\sin\theta_i\cos\theta_i= \frac{(2^i-1)\sqrt{2^{i+1}-1}}{2^{2i-1}}.
$$
The area
between the $(i-1)$st and $i$th horizontal slice inside the circle
is $C_{i-1}-C_i$. By subtracting the area $R^2\sqrt{2^{i+1}-1}/2^{2i}$ of the $i$th
triangle one obtains the sum of the eastern and western areas of the (sort of)
chopped segments in the areas EKG, GLI, KFH and so on without some type of
formal integration.

Comment: Very interesting thank you. I wonder if this summation can somehow be used as an expression or an approximation of $π$